# Query between two times with mongodb

Tags: mongodb

First of all, sorry if my question is obvious, but i'm having some troubles to do a specific query with mongodb.

Let's assume i have a collection with the following documents :

```
+----+--------+---------------------+
| ID |  user  |     record_date     |
+----+--------+---------------------+
|  1 | Frank  | 2017-05-10 12:13:15 |
|  2 | Ian    | 2017-05-10 13:15:18 |
|  3 | Ian    | 2017-05-10 17:45:34 |
|  4 | Lip    | 2017-05-10 18:53:12 |
|  5 | Frank  | 2017-05-10 18:54:23 |
|  6 | Fiona  | 2017-05-10 20:12:48 |
|  7 | Debbie | 2017-05-11 05:05:12 |
|  8 | Ian    | 2017-05-11 08:17:38 |
|  9 | Debbie | 2017-05-11 08:30:57 |
| 10 | Carl   | 2017-05-11 14:17:18 |
+----+--------+---------------------+
```

I'm trying to get any document that have a record_date between a time interval, not a date interval : for example, all documents where the record_date time is between 17:00 and 19:00.

With postgres or mysql, this was kinda easy : i converted the date value to a number (ex for the first document : 1213) and a simple query like record_date BETWEEN(1700,1900), but i'm having troubles getting the same results with mongo.

Does anyone have an idea to do such a request ?

Thanks a lot !

Jim

Comment: which server side technology you'r using ?

Comment: The server is a debian 8.2, mongodb 2.4.10. The app uses Laravel (php)

Comment: Did you try the answer?

Comment: @IshanSoni God it was already a week ago. I din't had time for now, I'll keep in touch asap, i'm really sorry !

Answer (score 0):

```
db.times.aggregate([{"$project": {time : {"$dateToString": {format : "%H", 
date : "$record_date"}}}}, {"$match" : {time: {"$gte":"17","$lte":"19"}}}])
```

This aggregation pipeline takes out the time part(specifically the Hour part using the format "%H") using $dateToString aggregation operator in the project phase and then uses a match phase to filter the results.
Ref - [$dateToString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/)

If you need to know more about how the aggregation pipeline works - [Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/)

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
db.record.aggregate([
    {
      $match:{
         $and: [
          {
            record_date: {
              $gte: "2017-05-10 17:00:00",
            },
          },
          {
            record_date: {
              $lte: "2017-05-10 19:59:59",
            },
          },
        ]
      }
    }
    ])
```